# how to get the radial gradient to start from the centre of the pie chart?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

In [my pie chart with grid lines](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/duqvLndh/1/), I have integrated a radial gradient. The problem is that it there is a gradient for every pie. I actually want a gradient which is common and it originates from the center of the pie chart.

I tried:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.attr('fill', 'url(#gradient)')
.outerRadius(function(d) { return 50 + (radius - 50) * d.data.percent / 100; })
.innerRadius(20);
```

but it didnt help.

How to get the radial gradient to start from the centre of the pie chart?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/duqvLndh/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JSFiddle you are using the wrong attributes. RadialGradient does not have x1, x2, etc. It has cx, cy and so on.

On your `<radialGradient>` tag, add an attribute called [`gradientUnits`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/gradientUnits) and set its value to `"userSpaceOnUse"`.

This means that the gradient attribute percentages (cx, cy, etc.) will be considered for the entire SVG instead of just for a particular shape. Then adjust the values as needed.

Here is the working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/kqfnuavq/

Comment: I think that worked. But the gradient's center is not at the center of the pie chart. How do I move that? http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/duqvLndh/2/

Comment: @RahulDesai You have to adjust `cx`, `cy`, and `r` as needed. [I've done that here](http://jsfiddle.net/duqvLndh/3/). +1 for this good answer.